# Cannot load System.Web.HttpContext error with razor pages and WebMail

Tags: c#, asp.net, razor-pages, .net-6.0

I've been having trouble getting WebMail to work sending an email using a contact form using  [This Official Microsoft Tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-pages/overview/getting-started/11-adding-email-to-your-web-site). My current issue is that I'm getting the error:

**Could not load type 'System.Web.HttpContext' from assembly 'System.Web, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'.**

After searching online I'm finding a lot of answers saying that I simply **cant** use System.Web, HttpContext, or add the necessary assemblies which I find hard to believe considering I have it set up exactly as the tutorial provides.Any and all help is greatly appreciated.

My usings:

```
@using System.Web;
@using System.Web.Helpers;
```

My code which runs after submitting my form:

```
@{
     ViewData["Title"] = "Email Confirmation";

            var clientEmail = Request.Form["clientEmail"];
            var clientName = Request.Form["clientName"];
            var clientPhone = Request.Form["clientPhone"];
            var clientMessage = Request.Form["clientMessage"];
            var errorMessage = "";
            var debuggingFlag = false;
            try
            {
                // Initialize WebMail helper
                WebMail.SmtpServer = "smtp.myserver.com";
                WebMail.SmtpPort = 587;
                WebMail.UserName = "MYEMAIL";
                WebMail.Password = "MYPASSWORD";
                WebMail.From = "MYEMAIL";
                WebMail.EnableSsl = true;


                // Send email
                WebMail.Send(to: "MYEMAIL",
                    subject: $"Message from {clientName}",
                    body: $"{clientMessage}\nPhone: {clientPhone}\nEmail: {clientEmail}"
                );
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                errorMessage = ex.Message;
            }
}
```

**EDIT**
I've also tried adding the System.Web.dll assembly but I'm getting the message that **The reference is invalid or unsupported**
Here is my csproj if it helps:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
    <RootNamespace>MYRAZORSITE</RootNamespace>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="bootstrap" Version="5.1.3" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNet.WebPages" Version="3.2.8" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

Comment: Looks like your problem is with the assemblies you've got in your solution. The information is a bit sparse to conclude what the problem is. Show some code please and error messages, etc.

Comment: @PaulSinnema Added code above, and that error message is the only one I'm receiving.

Comment: Is there a reason you’ve started this project in .Net Framework 4.x? If I may suggest, start a Blazor project with .Net 6.0 and be amazed at what it can do for you. It takes a bit getting used to and I would encourage reading the documentation beforehand about the Server Hosted or WASM variants. For sending mail I would use the SmtpClient class. Take a look here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.mail.smtpclient?view=net-6.0